# Slide down hidden element from top of the page when you click a image/button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hidden, slide

I'm trying to achieve a simple drop down box with text inside it, when I click a button/image it will drop down into view from hidden off the top of the webpage. I don't want it to expand and push existing content down, I want it to slide down over existing content sat on top with a higher z-index.

Does anybody know the best way to go about doing this?

Any help would be great, thank you!

Update with fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/92Jq9/

```
<div style="height:100%">
<span id="button">open slider 1</span>

    <div id="slider"> <span id="button4">close</span>
    </div>
</div>

$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#slider').addClass('in');
});

$('#button4').click(function(){
    $('#slider').removeClass('in');
});


html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
}
```

Basically want this but it doesn't seem to work in older version of Safari so need it to work cross browser, thanks for your help.

Comment: sounds like Position absolute would probably be the way to do this but more code for what you have tried already would help possible create something in a jsfiddle

Comment: Have been looking for similar examples on the web but everything I've tried doesn't seem to be working in latest version of jQuery. Not great with JS either so struggling a bit.

Comment: Sorry wrong fiddle, meant this one http://jsfiddle.net/92Jq9/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you trying to use? i just switched it to 1.11.0 and it still works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/jkDUm/59/

Then trying it with jQuery 2.1.0 it still works http://jsfiddle.net/jkDUm/60/

Comment: Seems to be my version of Safari 6.0.5 doesn't want to slide it in smooth. Tried it on a newer version of Safari and it works. Any idea why this might be or a cross browser/version way of doing it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exact code from your fiddle, but this way you could add multiple sliders, by only using the script once.

**Note:** You will have to do your style like panel, panel_2, and so on depending on how many sliders you want.

```
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    div.panel,p.flip
    {
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    div.panel
    {
    height:100px;
    display:none;
    }
    </style>
```

Then add text

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the jquery.transit package. 
Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dQrg/3/)

The div has a fixed heigth of 40px and is positioned absolute at -40px, so its right outside the viewport.
With the click of the button, the positioning is changed to relative and the offset between the container div and the box is calculated.
The box is then placed at -offset (right outside of view) and transitioned to zero:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
    $('.flyer').css('position', 'relative' );
    var flyer = $('#flyer');    
    var offset = flyer.offset(); 
    var yOffset = offset.top + 40;
    $('#flyer').css('top','-'+yOffset+'px');    
    $('#flyer').transition({ y: yOffset +'px' });    
});
```

This acutally moves a text box to the desired position, and does not create an overlay of full width or height, as the prevous answer does. This is how I understood the question.